# Workbox - SPA - fallback to /index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, workbox

I'm using [workbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox) with webpack to generate a service worker.

With the following code in `webpack.config.js`:

```
new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
  swSrc: "./src/sw.js"
}),
```

a service worker is generated nicely.

In `./src/sw.js`, I have:

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);
```

And all of my assets are precached nicely.

However, I have a single page application and I noticed that when refreshing the page while offline from a non-homepage route, the service worker doesn't respond. For example, when refreshing `/page1` while offline doesn't work, but refreshing `/` does work.

How can I configure workbox to use a runtime strategy that uses `/index.html` as a fallback for HTML requests?

## Note

Doing something like this:

```
new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
  swSrc: "./src/sw.js",
  navigationFallback: "/index.html"
})
```

does not work since `navigationFallback` is not a valid option in it's above usage.

```
{ message: '"navigationFallback" is not a supported parameter.'
```

Comment: register a route in the version of SW that u inject the manifest into. the regex can match the html's u wish to cover and the target can be 'index.html' .  review docs for WB.registerRoute()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For workbox v4 or below, use `workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute` (see another answer).

The recipe is [changed](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v4#navigation_route_changes) in v5:

```js
import {precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL} from 'workbox-precaching'
import {NavigationRoute, registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing'


precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)
registerRoute(new NavigationRoute(createHandlerBoundToURL('/index.html')))
```

Note: `self.__WB_MANIFEST` (renamed from `self.__precacheManifest`) is provided by `WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest`.

Answer (score 14):

Luckily, workbox has made this an easy solve.

> If your site is a single page app, you can use a NavigationRoute to return a specific response for all navigation requests.

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/single-page-app.html');
```

In my case:

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_navigation_route